# SpringSyncTransaction with Grails Searchable

Tags: spring, grails, transactions, searchable, compass-lucene

I'm trying to use the SpringSyncTransaction with the Grails Searchable plugin but can't set the transactionManager on the LocalCompassBean as suggested.  It appears that Searchable does not use the LocalCompassBean.

This problem stems from wanting to batch DomainClass.save() calls to reduce disk I/O on the lucene index.

Until now, I've been nesting the spring transaction within a compass transaction using the LocalTransactionFactory.  This has been causing issues, and ideally the two transactions would be synced up.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

http://www.compass-project.org/docs/2.1.0/reference/html/spring-transaction.html